# Creating and exporting a dataframe from a requested dataset in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

> I have an .xlsx file that contains 5 columns and 4500 rows of data. The column with the header "Symbols" is of interest. For this Question I made a Column containing five cell values from the "Symbols" column in the .xlsx file. Currently, I can request data that shows stock price changes over different periods of time per cell value in the column.

| Symbols |
| --- |
| AAPL |
| AMZN |
| TSLA |
| MSFT |
| NVDA |

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests





data = pd.read_excel('allstockdata.xlsx')

tickers = list(data["Symbols"])
# Iterating through cell values in the "Symbol" Column
for i in tickers:

    i = str(i)
    # Adding cell value between two halves of incomplete url to form valid url
    alldata = json.loads(requests.get(urlhalf1 + i + urlhalf2).text)
    # prints metrics for current cell value in iteration
    print(alldata)
```

> Current Output:

```
[{'symbol': 'AAPL', '1D': 1.15, '5D': 3.09, '1M': 15.46, '3M': -9.03, '6M': -11.56, 'ytd': -17.49, '1Y': 1.14, '3Y': 192.73, '5Y': 301.63, '10Y': 592.67, 'max': 115415.38}]
[{'symbol': 'AMZN', '1D': 2.64, '5D': -0.46, '1M': 9.54, '3M': -25.68, '6M': -28.55, 'ytd': -33.36, '1Y': -37.46, '3Y': 12.37, '5Y': 124.85, '10Y': 951.39, 'max': 113450.0}]
[{'symbol': 'TSLA', '1D': 0.74, '5D': -4.77, '1M': 12.65, '3M': -28.29, '6M': -30.11, 'ytd': -39.97, '1Y': 10.7, '3Y': 1320.51, '5Y': 1026.9, '10Y': 9916.69, 'max': 14966.95}]
[{'symbol': 'MSFT', '1D': 1.04, '5D': -3.36, '1M': 4.8, '3M': -8.48, '6M': -15.18, 'ytd': -23.31, '1Y': -8.65, '3Y': 84.82, '5Y': 249.99, '10Y': 772.01, 'max': 256620.0}]
[{'symbol': 'NVDA', '1D': 2.54, '5D': 1.52, '1M': 1.03, '3M': -27.64, '6M': -39.14, 'ytd': -47.660000000000004, '1Y': -16.85, '3Y': 278.62, '5Y': 288.04, '10Y': 5353.98, 'max': 41378.95}]
```

> Question:
>
> 1. From here, how can I get the datasets from each iteration into one DataFrame with the Keys in the nested dictionary as Columns and the Values as the Rows?
> 2. How can I export the final DataFrame into the original excel file (allstockdata.xlsx) so that the new data is aligned with the original data? (Should still have same # of rows)
>    Let me know if further clarification is needed. I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: so you need the dataframe with the columns from your dictionary key right?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that you have the data in a list as

```
data = [
    [{'symbol': 'AAPL', '1D': 1.15, '5D': 3.09, '1M': 15.46, '3M': -9.03, '6M': -11.56, 'ytd': -17.49, '1Y': 1.14, '3Y': 192.73, '5Y': 301.63, '10Y': 592.67, 'max': 115415.38}],
[{'symbol': 'AMZN', '1D': 2.64, '5D': -0.46, '1M': 9.54, '3M': -25.68, '6M': -28.55, 'ytd': -33.36, '1Y': -37.46, '3Y': 12.37, '5Y': 124.85, '10Y': 951.39, 'max': 113450.0}],
[{'symbol': 'TSLA', '1D': 0.74, '5D': -4.77, '1M': 12.65, '3M': -28.29, '6M': -30.11, 'ytd': -39.97, '1Y': 10.7, '3Y': 1320.51, '5Y': 1026.9, '10Y': 9916.69, 'max': 14966.95}],
[{'symbol': 'MSFT', '1D': 1.04, '5D': -3.36, '1M': 4.8, '3M': -8.48, '6M': -15.18, 'ytd': -23.31, '1Y': -8.65, '3Y': 84.82, '5Y': 249.99, '10Y': 772.01, 'max': 256620.0}],
[{'symbol': 'NVDA', '1D': 2.54, '5D': 1.52, '1M': 1.03, '3M': -27.64, '6M': -39.14, 'ytd': -47.660000000000004, '1Y': -16.85, '3Y': 278.62, '5Y': 288.04, '10Y': 5353.98, 'max': 41378.95}],
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['data'])
```

Once the values in lists are read as dictionary in dataframe we can convert the dictionaies obtained to columns using [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) or [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('data').apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1)
```

This gives us the expected output :

```
  symbol    1D    5D     1M     3M  ...     1Y       3Y       5Y      10Y        max
0   AAPL  1.15  3.09  15.46  -9.03  ...   1.14   192.73   301.63   592.67  115415.38
1   AMZN  2.64 -0.46   9.54 -25.68  ... -37.46    12.37   124.85   951.39  113450.00
2   TSLA  0.74 -4.77  12.65 -28.29  ...  10.70  1320.51  1026.90  9916.69   14966.95
3   MSFT  1.04 -3.36   4.80  -8.48  ...  -8.65    84.82   249.99   772.01  256620.00
4   NVDA  2.54  1.52   1.03 -27.64  ... -16.85   278.62   288.04  5353.98   41378.95

[5 rows x 12 columns]
```

Now you can write the data to the xlsx file

```
df.to_excel("allstockdata.xlsx")
```

Comment: so when I applied this code to the actual excel file I got a few errors:                  columns = _validate_or_indexify_columns(contents, columns)  and  f"{len(columns)} columns passed, passed data had "
AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns          What could be the issue?

Comment: That's because in the answer, as I said the dataframe contains only one column which is a list of dictionary, and you may have had multiple columns

Comment: Can you ask a separate question with your original excel file uploaded and the error code that you are getting. I ll answer it there

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015186/errors-while-creating-and-exporting-dataframe-to-excel