# Errors while Creating and Exporting DataFrame to Excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, dataframe, loops

> I have an excel file with 5 columns and 4500 rows of data. The image is a sample of 5 rows from the file that will be iterated through in this code.
> [image: allstockdata.xlsx]'
> allstockdata.xlsx

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests





file = pd.read_excel('allstockdata.xlsx')
data = []
tickers = list(file["Symbol"])
for i in tickers:

    i = str(i)
    # adds symbol between 2 halves of an incomplete url to form a valid url to request data from
    alldata = json.loads(requests.get(urlhalf1 + i + urlhalf2).text)
# nests dataset in list
data.append(alldata)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['data'])
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('data').apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1)
df.to_excel('allstockdata.xlsx')
```

> Error: columns = _validate_or_indexify_columns(contents, columns)

> Error: f"{len(columns)} columns passed, passed data had "
> AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns

> Question: How do I fix these errors in my code? How can I skip iterations that form invalid urls(no available data on specific symbol)? Considering the size of the excel file (5 columns, 4500 rows), should I iterate in increments?

> Please ask for clarification if necessary

Comment: Can you share the excel file please from which you are reading!

Comment: where do I go to do that?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g6h-Arauu2pF2NLMWYarsxDoMLzpznTk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110875782292688501297&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: let me know if you have trouble viewing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `allData` to the `data` list. For testing purpose you can try my code for first 10 rows, I have edited accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

file = pd.read_excel('allstockdata.xlsx')
file = file.iloc[:10] # For testing purpose try with first 10 rows 
data = []
tickers = list(file["Symbol"])

for i in tickers:
    response = requests.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock-price-change/' + str(i) + '?apikey=YOURAPIKEY')
    alldata = json.loads(response.text)
    data.append(alldata)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['data'])
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('data').apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1)
df.to_excel('allstockdata.xlsx')
```

This gives us the expected output

[image]

Comment: it has been done